# Iphone 6 security answers forgotten

Tags: iphone

I have forgotten my apple rescue email address, how can I find it.  Because I have forgotten my security answers I have clicked the email link, but do not recognise the address the resetting is being sent to.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Recovery Key issued by Apple? I know that when I was updating my security questions or my AppleID that they issued me a Recovery Key which is used to access your account when you forget your password, security questions, etc. If not, I would most likely go to an Apple Store to see if they can help sort this out. Hope this helps and good luck.